# How to convert an object to a string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I want to assign the name of the current directory to construct the path of a parallel directory (to run some diff commands).

However when I do this:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name my_test_dir;
Set-Location my_test_dir;
$a = $( Get-Item . | Select-Object Name ); 
write-host( "x${a}x" );
```

I get

> x@{Name=my_test_dir}x

instead of what I *expected*:

> xmy_test_dirx

So, how do I "unbox" the name of the directory?

---

PS - for ease of testing I use:

```
mkdir my_test_dir; cd my_test_dir; $a = $( Get-Item . | Select Name ); echo "x${a}x"; cd ..; rmdir my_test_dir
```

Comment: Use `select-object -expand name`. Objects have property/value pairs unless they are primitives. So you must do something different to get the value only. Another way is to use member access: `$a.name`

Comment: To save the overhead of the pipeline, you can get the name like this: `$a = (Get-Item .).Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `... |Select-Object PropertyName`, it produces an object with a property named `PropertyName`, copying the value from the corresponding property on the input item.

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty PropertyName` or `ForEach-Object MemberName` to get just the value of the property:

```
$a = Get-Item . | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
# or 
$a = Get-Item . | ForEach-Object Name
```

... or reference the property directly:

```
$a = (Get-Item .).Name
```